# how to filter flow returned by one repository by another repository without blocking?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I have a service that gets all friends of a user and it should filter out the users that are either blocked by the user or that are blocking the user.

This is my approach so far. There are two repositories.

One for the friendship information:

```kotlin
interface FriendshipRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Friendship, Long> {
  fun findByUserId(userId: Long): Flow<Friendship>
}
```

and one for the block-information:

```kotlin
interface BlockRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<Block, Long> {
  fun findByUserIdAndFriendIdIn(userId: Long, friendId: Set<Long>): Flow<Block>
  fun findByUserIdInAndFriendId(userId: Set<Long>, friendId: Long): Flow<Block>
}
```

### Question

I have two problems with this.

1. I need to block to collect the friend-ids before I can query the `blockRepository`.
2. I don't know how to filter the original flow without blocking the result of the blockRepository, because I need to know all blocks.

This implementation works - and it looks weird to me, because of the `asFlux` and `block()!!` operations, but I cannot come up with a better solution:

```kotlin
override suspend fun findFriendIdsByUserId(userId: Long): Flow<Long> {
  val friends = friendshipRepository.findByUserId(userId)
    .filter { it.status == FRIEND }
    .map { it.friendId }
    .asFlux()
    .collectList()
    .block()!!
    .toMutableSet()

  val userBlocks = blockRepository.findByUserIdAndFriendIdIn(userId, friends)
  val userIsBlockedBy = blockRepository.findByUserIdInAndFriendId(friends, userId)

  val blocks =  userBlocks.asFlux().mergeWith(userIsBlockedBy.asFlux())
    .map { it.friendId }
    .collectList()
    .block()!!
    .toSet()
  friends.removeAll(blocks)
  return friends.asFlow()
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why does `findByUserId` return a flow? Does it actually return observable data or is it just a wrapper?

Comment: Another controller/service uses the same method to provide the list of friends (including blocked ones) to the frontend. It is more of a wrapper, but I think making it return Set would contradict using the reactive spring stack.

Comment: @Stuck Just out of curiosity, if you already have flows, why do you use `.asFlux()` all over the place instead of working with `Flow`s?

Comment: @Joffrey: Because there is no merge operator for flows. But I would be happy to keep them flows!

Comment: Mmh, what about [merge(vararg Flow)](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html)?

Comment: it is experimental

Comment: @Stuck do you have a strict no-experimental policy? That's harsh. I mean if this is ever removed or changed to a point where you can't use it, you can always fall back to a very simple non-fuseable implementation (you don't rely on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at least you can avoid blocking by relying on `Flow`'s suspending operators like `toSet()` instead of `Flux`'s  `block`:

```kotlin
override suspend fun findFriendIdsByUserId(userId: Long): Flow<Long> {
  val friends = friendshipRepository.findByUserId(userId)
    .filter { it.status == FRIEND }
    .map { it.friendId }
    .toSet()

  val userBlocks = blockRepository.findByUserIdAndFriendIdIn(userId, friends)
  val userIsBlockedBy = blockRepository.findByUserIdInAndFriendId(friends, userId)

  val blocks = merge(userBlocks, userIsBlockedBy)
    .map { it.friendId }
    .toSet()

  return (friends - blocks).asFlow()
}
```

But since you need to know all the values of `blocks` to be able to even start filtering, and you need all `friends` to know the `blocks`, I'm not sure you can do better without redesigning the DB.

Comment: I think the answer is fine, I can get rid of the experimental `merge` by `.asFlux().mergeWith(b.asFlux()).asFlow()`

Comment: Honestly you don't even need `merge()` at all if you end up with a `Set` anyway, you could just add the 2 resulting sets together directly

Comment: yes, and there was a bug anyway, because the filter is different for `userBlocks` and `userIsBlockedBy' so I immediately convert these to sets and then just add them.